# IVdsPack::CreateVolume

Tags: c++, c, windows

```
HRESULT CreatePartitionEx(ULONGLONG ullOffset, ULONGLONG ullSize, ULONG ulAlign,  [in]   CREATE_PARTITION_PARAMETERS *para, IVdsAsync **ppAsync
)
```

When i am passing parameter `ppAsync = NULL` , perticular call is failing and returned INVALIED argument.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You need to accept more answers.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), concerning the last parameter - `ppAsync`:

> The address of an IVdsAsync interface pointer, which VDS initializes
>   on return. Callers must release the interface. Use this pointer to
>   cancel, wait for, or query the status of the operation.

This means that you should provide an actual pointer as a last parameter when calling the function. Since you are providing NULL, probably that is causing the problem.

**EDIT**:

Use like this:

```
IVdsAsync *pAsync;    // Declare a pointer
// Then use it like this (take a look at the last parameter)
CreatePartitionEx(
    ullOffset,
    ullSize,
    ulAlign,
    para,
    &pAsync);    // You pass it with a leading &, which gives you the address of the pointer
```

And that should do it.

Remember that you should release the `pAsync` after you are finished with it, as the documentation states.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please help me to create valid pointer as last parameters or give me some example code which will help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I used like this only.but i am getting same error.                       IVdsAsync *ppsync;                                                     HRESULT vol_created1; 
 VDS_ASYNC_OUTPUT AsyncOut;

 //VDS_ASYNC_OUTPUT *pAsyncOut = NULL;
 //ZeroMemory( &AsyncOut, sizeof(VDS_ASYNC_OUTPUT));
//vol_created1=ppsync->Cancel();
//vol_created1=ppsync->Wait (&vol_created,pAsyncOut);
//VDS_ASYNC_OUTPUT    AsyncOut;
 vol_created=pPack->CreateVolume(VDS_VT_SIMPLE,&input_disk,1,0,&ppsync);                 Please this code.

Comment: And what about the other parameters. You are passing `0` as `CREATE_PARTITION_PARAMETERS` (fourth parameter), which is `PARTITION_ENTRY_UNUSED`. I don't know what the function does if such thing is passed.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing  with Createvolume() , buts its returning hResult= E_InvalidArg . The fourth parameter is stripe size .The Windows implementation requires the stripe size to be 65536 if the type is VDS_VT_STRIPE or VDS_VT_PaARITY. Other volume types are not striped and the stripe size is 0.